# C# code highlighting for "async" and "await"

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Can we have code highlighting for [`async` and `await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) in C#?

`async` and `await` was released with *.NET Framework 4.5*.

> Visual Studio 2012 introduces a simplified approach, async programming, that leverages asynchronous support in the .NET Framework 4.5 and the Windows Runtime. The compiler does the difficult work that the developer used to do, and your application retains a logical structure that resembles synchronous code. As a result, you get all the advantages of asynchronous programming with a fraction of the effort.

`async` and `await` will not be recognised by the highlighter as you can see here:

```cs
public async void Foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: To be clear: are you saying the language highlighter doesn't recognise `async` or `await` for C#?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I updated my post

Comment: I guess that's a feature-request on google prettify, nothing SE can do about it...

Comment: @Deduplicator thank you, I found an already existing issiue on [Github](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/265)

Comment: If it is not something SE can change because it is how third party implemented that feature, then I believe this is `status-bydesign`.